# get part of the path in recursive operation

Tags: windows-7, batch

I have a directory tree like this

```
c:\work\src\A\D1\foo.txt
c:\work\src\A\D2\foo.txt
c:\work\src\B\foo.txt
```

I want to run the stream editor (sed) for each foo.txt and replace some text with sed. The destination would look like this:

```
c:\work\dst\A\D1\foo.txt
c:\work\dst\A\D2\foo.txt
c:\work\dst\B\foo.txt
```

I tried to find all foot.txt with the for command of the windows command processor, but I don't know how to get the part from the base directory:

```
cd c:\work\src
FOR /R %d in (sources) DO sed %d > c:\work\dst\%d
```

This doesn't work since %d expands to `c:\work\src\A\D1\foo.txt` instead of `A\D1\foo.txt`.

How can I iterate through all files and build the target path appropriately?

*edit*

I use sed and I could use it for the path names too. I could store the path names in a file to allow sed to patch them:

```
set dst=c:\work\dst\
del /f foo.tmp
FOR /R %%d in (.) DO @echo %%d >> foo.tmp
sed s/C:\\work\\src\\// foo.tmp > bah.tmp
FOR /F IN (bah.tmp) DO sed -f patch.sed %%i > %dst%\%%i
del foo.tmp bah.tmp
```

This approach has the drawback that the current directory can't be obtained from `%CD%` but has to be hard coded since sed requires escaped backslashes. Further I have to fight with the temporary files too. Is there a more elegant way like

```
FOR /R "c:\work\src" /D %%d IN (foo.txt) DO @if exist %%d  sed ????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same concept as Kevin' script. Just a tad shorter. :-)

```
@echo off
::Get the directory from whence the script was called
set CWD=%~dp0
set CWD
for /R %%g in (foo.txt) do (if exist "%%g" call :GetPath "%%g")
goto :exit  

:GetPath
if not exist "%~1" goto :EOF
echo Original: %~1
set _nfile=%~1
call set _nfile=%%_nfile:%CWD%=%%
echo NFile: %_nfile%
goto :EOF

:exit
set CWD=
set _nfile=
```

Add you SED command in the "GetPath" routine and pass the `_nfile` variable.

Comment: The most important part was the replace `_nfile=%%_nfile:old=new%%. I missed this specifically. Any idea where I get this in the help at the command prompt?

Comment: You can always do a `set /?` from the command-line, which displays a help screen for the set command. But finding some of the more `useful` undocumented commands comes from users trial-and-error. For example, the `call set _nfile...` part is not documented in the help file. But you can find information about it online: http://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Answer (score 0):

OK, I setup the same set of test files:

```
X:\>dir /s /b
X:\work
X:\work\src
X:\work\src\A
X:\work\src\B
X:\work\src\A\D1
X:\work\src\A\D2
X:\work\src\A\D1\foo.txt
X:\work\src\A\D2\foo.txt
X:\work\src\B\foo.txt
```

Then, I have a batch file. Let's say it's saved as: `"D:\batchscript.cmd"`:

```
@echo off

rem get the "unique" part of the source and dest paths: "\src\", "\dst\"
set "zusource=\src\"
set "zudest=\dst\"



rem From within the current directory, and all subdirectories,
rem process each file named "foo.txt"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir /s /b "foo.txt"`) do call :work "%%~f"

rem We are done. Go "exit" the script.
goto :EOF



:work
rem get the full name of the current "source" file: "X:\work\src\A\D1\foo.txt"
set "zsourcefq=%~1"



rem substitute the "unique" parts:
rem get "X:\work\dst\A\D1\foo.txt" from "X:\work\src\A\D1\foo.txt"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%g in (`echo set "zdestfq=%%zsourcefq:%zusource%=%zudest%%%"`) do %%g



rem make the destination directory if necessaary: "X:\work\dst\A\D1"
rem two ways, first relies on your specific file "name", second is "universal"

rem md "%zdestfq:foo.txt=%" 2>nul
for %%g in ("%zdestfq%") do md "%%~dpg" 2>nul



echo Processing: "%zsourcefq%" --^> "%zdestfq%"

rem do your "sed" command here
echo     sed -r "s/whatever/whateverelse/g" "%zsourcefq%" ^> "%zdestfq%"

goto :EOF
```

To use the scirpt, first change to the "source" directory:

```
X:\>CD /D "X:\work\src"
X:\work\src>
```

Then, run the script:

```
X:\work\src>"D:\batchscript.cmd"
Processing: "X:\work\src\A\D1\foo.txt" --> "X:\work\dst\A\D1\foo.txt"
    sed -r "s/whatever/whateverelse/g" "X:\work\src\A\D1\foo.txt" > "X:\work\dst\A\D1\foo.txt"
Processing: "X:\work\src\A\D2\foo.txt" --> "X:\work\dst\A\D2\foo.txt"
    sed -r "s/whatever/whateverelse/g" "X:\work\src\A\D2\foo.txt" > "X:\work\dst\A\D2\foo.txt"
Processing: "X:\work\src\B\foo.txt" --> "X:\work\dst\B\foo.txt"
    sed -r "s/whatever/whateverelse/g" "X:\work\src\B\foo.txt" > "X:\work\dst\B\foo.txt"
```

Change the line that begins: `"echo    sed -r..."` to whatever sed command you need.